# The grammar of '... produces so much more wealth than there are useful things to spend it on that we have to spend it on ...'

Tags: meaning, grammar

There is a sentence in Longman Advanced Grammar sduty section 2.

> Technological capitalism produces so much more wealth than there are useful things to spend it on that we have to spend it on rubbish.

KrisW explain the grammar point about Comparative deletion very clearly. But I'm still confused about something.

In KrisW's opinion, the sentence is simply comparing the magnitude from the first clause with the magnitude of the second clause. The first clause is "wealth", and the second is "things there are to spend it (wealth) on".

So, why use "there are" ?

Can we modify the sentence as below ?

> Technological capitalism produces so much more wealth than  useful things 
>   that we have to spend it on rubbish.

Comment: *There are* means *there exist* (but is much more idiomatic). If you leave out it out, the sentence means that the useful things are produced by technological capitalism, whereas the original version does not say that. I also find the *it* a bit awkward in the second version.

Comment: Indeed, the "useful things" are not what are made, but what the money is spent on. So the proposed sentence loses the meaning of the original.

Comment: There are useful things to spend money on: A, B, C ...N.* Technological capitalism produces great wealth, much more than we need to buy / facilitate A ...N. There's so much excess money that we have to spend it somehow**, so we're really forced into spending it on rubbish***. /// * – What these 'useful things' are will be opinion-based, and probably technology-informed // ** – There may well be sound economic reasons _why_ the money needs recycling rather than putting under the bed. // *** – Again, opinion-based (though probably a fair comment).

Comment: @Minty Good argument that gets to the heart of the matter. Consider converting your comment into an answer.